# How link a view in IOS programatically

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

i have developed many app for android now i am learning IOS.I want know that as in android we link a view by id like this

TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView);

How can i do the same in IOS to identify a view.

Thanks.

Comment: You should take a look at the [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ConnectTheUIToCode.html)

Comment: @chengsam it connects whole scene to a class,i want to identify a particular view in a class how can i do that.

Comment: you can access outlet by its name

Comment: @DkThakur You should read the doc thoroughly, it did teach you how to connect the views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.You can do  this by viewWithTag.

1.Assign a tag number to a view.

[image]

2.identify a view by viewWithTag like this

```
 UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
 //then change the properties
 [btn setTitle:@"Press Me" forState:UIControlState];
 //etc etc
```

3.Now you can do more stuff you want.

Answer (score 1):

iOS works on bit different way.

- Simply add a textview to your ViewController Scene in  storyboard.
- Next open your viewController in Assistant editor on top right corner
  of xcode.
- select textview Control drag the blue linking line from Storyboard
  scene to ViewController for creating property/Outlet.
- Select its type outlet/Action, name etc. and its done use it from
  your ViewDidLoad.

for more reference https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_actions_and_outlets.htm

Comment: Thanks for the answer yeah i know this procedure but i want to know that without drag and drop how i can identify a view programatically like its name or id something like android.